# How to web request filtering - block one particular country

Tags: filter, request

My MVC-5 website gets a lot of false registrations, or real and followed by experiments in escalation of privileges.  I can write a request filter - but how to block web requests from one particular country?  Are there publicly available list of IPs that I can block ... or what?  How do people approach solving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the country you might have a little difficulty in blocking everything but there are lists out there (such as the one maintained by [nirsoft](https://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/)). Usually it's better to block specific IP addresses where the bad behavior is originating by using software that watches for the behavior and dynamically blocks it. That way you're covered regardless of where it originates. Especially since managing IP address blacklists is a real pain. I've made use of IPTables on linux before for this and it works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks.  I was reading up on using <ipsecurity> in web.config, and it sounds like it is not reliable.  IP security roles have to be enabled on the IIS server of your hosting company (mine is, thankfully), but you're always at risk of something changing in the next update of IIS.  For those using MVC (like me), it's better to go to NirSoft, download a CSV list, then use a macro to convert that into a static C# list that you can check an IP against in an action filter... this also allows you to redirect the user to a graceful "Nope ... Not YOU!!" web page etc.  I think that's what I'll do.